# Opentok display’s black video

Tags: opentok, tokbox

I’m running basic_video_chat application from opentok linux sdk examples, There was an audio problem on the hardware so, I had set `otc_publisher_set_publish_audio (g_publisher, false)` and `otc_publisher_set_audio_fallback_enabled(g_publisher, false)`, then it created a session and started to stream video, but I get black video on opentok playground.

I tested my webcam with other application and it is working fine, webcam activity LED turned on while running application so webcam is also getting accessed. Also, I can hear audio from the subscriber side, but subscriber can't see my published video.

Comment: Can you provide the logs from the linux side?  Are on_publisher_stream_created and on_publisher_render_frame functions called?

Comment: @ggarber Thanks for the reply. Issue was resolved, it was due to API Key miss configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Found solution, I need to allow Vp8 codec in API Key configuration.